# Memoji/Animoji transparent background video

Tags: video, graphics, animoji

**TL;DR: I want to get a Memoji video with a transparent background.**

When I record a Memoji video in Messages, the video clearly has no background (transparent) as switching between light/dark mode (in iOS 13) switches the background of the video in Messages and in the camera roll between black and white.

However, if I save the Memoji video and airdrop or email it to my Mac and load it into a video editing software (final cut pro) or into photoshop, the video has a black background. I need the transparent background version of the video as I want to use it for a personal website I'm building that will have a light/dark mode where the background of the website changes colour behind the Memoji.

Is there any way for me to get a Memoji video file with the transparent background?

If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how I could best edit out the black background? I have tried after effects but the rotoscoping didn't work perfectly, and I don't want to have to cut it out frame by frame in photoshop as the video is ~10 seconds long.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you're making the assumption that Memoji in Messages has a transparent background.  I believe the background is coded so that it displays black/white based on if the app is in Dark Mode or not.  FLV, F4V, AVI or Quicktime support transparent backgrounds.  Have you tried exporting in one of these formats?

Comment: @fsb I am assuming that yes and I definitely agree it could be coded to switch depending on what mode you're in. How would I export as one of those formats? Airdrop the video to my Mac and then export it as one of those formats in final cut pro? or is there a way to do it straight from the iPhone?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'm not aware of any way to do that on an iPhone (but maybe someone else here knows how to do it).  I think the way you indicated is probably the best way to convert and edit the video.

Comment: @fsb I guess I'll have to do some research into it as every way I'm trying to export the video isn't working...

Comment: @fsb I feel like the problem may be that the .mov file given when you share the Memoji does not include the data for the alpha transparency so there is not way to get it no matter what video format I convert to...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that saving a Memoji will remove the alpha channel. A workaround is to launch Messages on your Mac and then send the Memoji to yourself. Once received in Messages, do not use the download or save options. Instead, right-click and select Open. This will open the video in Quicktime. You can save from here and it will preserve the alpha (transparent) channel.